# Application of Jensen's Inequality. Correct?

Tags: integration, inequality, entropy

Help would be appreciated.

Consider $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=x^2$ which is convex
we want to show that $\mathbb{E}\Big[f(X)\Big] \geq f\Big[\mathbb{E}(X)\Big]$. Therefore,
$\mathbb{E}\Big[X^{2}\Big] \geq \Big[\mathbb{E}(X)\Big]^{2}$
i.e.
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{2}\cdot x^{2} \mathrm{d}x = \tfrac{1}{5} \geq \Big[\int_{0}^{1} x \cdot x^{2} \mathrm{d}x \Big]^{2} = \tfrac{1}{4}^{2} = \tfrac{1}{16}$$.

Is my logic correct or have I missed something out by the theorem itself?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$?

Comment: First, you are not "showing that $\mathbb{E}\Big[f(X)\Big] \geq f\Big[\mathbb{E}(X)\Big]$" (that's esentially Jensen's inequality), at most you are trying to check it's true for a single special case. Second, you are not telling us what is the density (probability distribution) of $X$, hence, we cannot compute $E(X)$

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for your reply. I'm unsure how to specify the density of X